# Show that the Language L is not regular (pumping lemma)

Tags: pumping-lemma, check-my-answer

$L = \{cda^nb^n\mid n\in \Bbb N\} \cup \{a,b,d\}^*$

Assuming $L$ is regular then there exist a pumping length $n$ for $L$. Lets use w = $cda^nb^n$.

Thus $w \in L$ and $|w| = 2n+2$ 
$\implies$ $|w| \geq n$.

$w$ can be splitted into three pieces $w = xyz$ with the following conditions:

- $|xy| \leq n$
- $|y| \geq 1$

Let be $x = cda^j$ and $y = a^k$ with $ k+j\leq n$ and $ k\geq 1$.

Now choose $i = 2$ so that $xy^iz = xyyz = cda^ja^ka^ka^{n-j-k}b^n = cda^{n+k}b^n$

$w$ has now more $a$'s than $b$'s (considering that $k$ is at least 1) $\implies w \notin L \implies$ $L$ is not regular.

**Is that enough for the proof?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to grade work with no specific concerns raised.

Comment: i defined $cda^j$ and $y=a^k$ with $k+j \leq n$, but if $ k + j = n$then i have a problem because $|xy|$ is now greater than n. Maybe i could change the definition to $k + j \leq n-2$? 

Another question i have: can there be multiple correct choices for x,y and z which leads to the right conclusion? For example $x = cd$, $y = a^k with$  $1 \leq k \leq n-2$ which implies to the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain the easiest way to show that this language isn't context-free. It it were, then its intersection with $c(a+b+d)^*$ would also be. This intersection is $cda^nb^n$. If the latter were context-free, then if we applied the homomorphism that erases $c,d$, the resulting language $a^nb^n$ would also be context-free; but we know that $a^nb^n$ isn't context-free.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be right, but I want to understand the pumping lemma. I would appreciate it if you could tell me where I made a mistake.

Comment: You chose the decomposition of $w$ into $xyz$. You cannot do this. Rather, the decomposition is given to you.